# How does one add UIButton to UIToolBar programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uitoolbar, programmatically-created

I have added the toolbar using Interface Builder, but I need to add the buttons at runtime / conditionally. I'm not getting any errors, but my dynamic buttons are not appearing on the toolbar. I have verified that arrayOfModulesScreens is loaded with the data I need. At least that works (:)). Do I need to add the buttons into a UIView, then add that view to the toolbar? Just thinking outloud. Perhaps there is a better approach to begin with? Thanks in advance for any clues leading to the resolve.

CustomFormController.h

```
@interface CustomFormController : UIViewController { 
    UIToolbar *screensBar;  
}
```

CustomFormController.m

```
EPData *epData = [[EPData alloc] init];
NSArray *screens = [epData loadPlistIntoArray:@"Screens"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"process_module_id == %@", process_modulesID];
NSArray *arrayOfModulesScreens = [screens filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

for(int i=0; i < [arrayOfModulesScreens count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dictRow = [arrayOfModulesScreens objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
    [button setTitle:[dictRow objectForKey:@"screen_title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [screensBar addSubview:button];  
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are actually wanting to add a UIBarButtonItem (not a UIButton) to the toolbar, you just create one or more UIBarButtonItems, put them in an NSArray (or NSMutableArray), and assign that array to the `items` property of the toolbar. See [the UIBarButtonItem documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details. Using your code above, that might look something like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfModulesScreens count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dictRow = [arrayOfModulesScreens objectAtIndex:i];
        UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[dictRow objectForKey:@"screen_title"]
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(buttonClick:)];
        [items addObject:button];
        [button release];
    }
    screensBar.items = items;
```

(you would, of course, then need to change your `buttonClick:` to expect a UIBarButtonItem instead of a UIButton).

If you're really wanting to put a UIButton in there, you first need to wrap the UIButton in a UIBarButtonItem, something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
```

Then add the item to the toolbar as above.

---

As for why your buttons aren't showing up in your posted code, the problem is that UIButton's `buttonWithType:` creates a button with zero width and zero height. You would need to resize the button (manually or by using `sizeToFit` after setting the title) to make it show. After fixing that, you would then see that the buttons are all on top of each other in the upper-left corner of the parent view; you would need to position them manually as appropriate.

Comment: That makes perfect sense as to why there was no image showing. Thanks for touching on that as well as providing a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the `navigationController` directly in your code like that.

A safer way would be this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[dictRow objectForKey:@"screen_title"]
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(buttonClick:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

Answer (score 1):

**ToolBar Approach**

One problem with adding `UIButton` to `UIToolBar` is that width of the button and positioning of the buttons is difficult to control

**Simpler Approach**

Remove the toolbar and place a `UIView` with the background image which is identical to your toolbar. Now you can add the `UIButton` as a subview to that view. This way you have more control over the positioning and the width of the buttons. Also you can add other views as well.